# How do you get a function pointer to a typed function in go?

Tags: go, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

The following code gets a pointer to the function `hello` and prints it:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type x struct {}
func (self *x) hello2(a int) {}

func hello(a int) {}

func main() {
    f1 := hello
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f1)

    // f2 := hello2
    // fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
}
```

However, if I un-comment the section at the bottom, the compile errors, saying:

```
> ./junk.go:14: undefined: hello2
```

So I tried:

```golang
  i := &x{}
  f2 := &i.hello2
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
```

...but that errors with:

```
> ./junk.go:15: method i.hello2 is not an expression, must be called
```

Ok, so maybe I have to directly refer to original type:

```golang
  f2 := x.hello2
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
```

Nope:

```
> ./junk.go:14: invalid method expression x.hello2 (needs pointer receiver: (*x).hello2)
> ./junk.go:14: x.hello2 undefined (type x has no method hello2)
```

This sort of works:

```golang
  i := &x{}
  f2 := reflect.TypeOf(i).Method(0)
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
```

However, the resulting `f2` is a `reflect.Method`, not a function pointer. :(

What is the appropriate syntax here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use method expressions, which will return a function that takes the receiver as the first argument.

```golang
f2 := (*x).hello2
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)

f2(&x{}, 123)
```

Otherwise you can just wrap the function call in a function that accepts the `x` as an argument.

```golang
f2 := func(val *x) {
    val.hello2(123)
}
```

Or that closes over an existing `x` value.

```golang
val := &x{}

f2 := func() {
    val.hello2(123)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Relevant reading on Go function calls and closures: "Go 1.1 Function Calls" by Russ Cox (which covers Go1 in details too).

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub